# Ruby on Rails repository using Capistrano 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm looking for open source Ruby on Rails repositories (on GitHub or elsewhere) that are using Capistrano 3 for production deployments. Specifically, I want to review (and learn from) one or more complete and correct Capistrano 3 configurations.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can't give a repo, but this slightly modified gist should get you started on Capistrano 3, it's a Rails & Mongoid 4, Capistrano 3 deploy script: 
https://gist.github.com/blackxored/7483765